# SignalR MVC4 Issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub, sqldependency

I am following this tutorial to integrate SignalR to my project http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/

So basically this is my View where I want to show my table.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PatientInfo";
}

<h2>PatientInfo</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.pName</h3>
<h5>@ViewBag.glucoseT</h5>

@if (Session["LogedUserFirstname"] != null)
{

    <text>
    <p>Welcome @Session["LogedUserFirstname"].ToString()</p>
    </text>

    @Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "Logout", "Home")


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div id="messagesTable"></div>
    </div>
</div>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
 <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/SignalR/Hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var notifications = $.connection.dataHub;

        //debugger;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        notifications.client.updateMessages = function () {
            getAllMessages()

        };
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            alert("connection started")
            getAllMessages();
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });


    function getAllMessages() {
        var tbl = $('#messagesTable');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/GetMessages',
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).success(function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);
        }).error(function () {

        });
    }
</script>



}
```

My project is running but the table doesn't appear at all. I started by pasting the view because I believe that the scripts are not executed in the first place; The Alert Message is NOT being shown even if I try to add one directly after

```
$(function () {
        alert("I am an alert box!");
```

This is my Layout.cshtml file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
 <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="SignalR/Hubs"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#p_table").dataTable();
        });
    </script>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012, MVC4.
Please Help..

Comment: It doesn't look like you've included jQuery? Unless it is in your _Layout.cshtml file

Comment: I have added this jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js and in my Layout view I added jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: I think you're probably referencing SignalR before jQuery - jQuery is a dependency of SignalR. This also explains why nothing is being executed on `doc.ready`. Move the reference to the SignalR script and to the Hub proxy into your Layout view after the reference to jQuery

Comment: I did still didn't work.. I also added $(document).ready(.. but nothing  :(

Comment: Take a look at my code https://github.com/adaam2/APoorMansTwitterStreamingClient/blob/master/TwitterClient.Web/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml - I have everything referenced in my Layout view and in an external JavaScript file!

Comment: I looked at it and it is similar to mine.. By the way I am using jquery for datatables and this is working so there is something weird about signalR I believe.. I will add my Layout to the question check it if you may.. Thanks alot for your help.. Hope it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have placed **all** your script tags from the view inside the `scripts` section of the view:

```
@section scripts {
    ... your <script> tags come here
}
```

The reason why your alerts don't work is because you have directly put them inside the body of the view which gets rendered at the `@RenderBody()` call of the Layout. But as you can see it's only at the end of this Layout that we have references to the scripts such as jQuery and signalr.

Now they will appear at the proper location: `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`.

By the way use the console window in your webbrowser to see potential script errors you might have. For example in your case it would display that jQuery is not defined error.

Another remark: don't include signalR script twice: right now you seem to have included `jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js` in your view and `jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js` in your Layout.

Comment: The alert box is now showing, but the table isn't yet.. So I believe now I can continue debugging the code having the scripts working.. Thank you so much